# Facebook Places and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

I am building a Rails app that will allow users to publish their location via Facebook Places and wondered where the best place to start was. The Facebooker gem? Can't find much activity around Rails and the Places API and am happy to roll my own but wondered if anyone was aware of an existing gem or plugin that would do the job?

Comment: I am developing a application and i need facebook places data. I am also fetching data from Foursquare. Will this works for that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best facebook gem i've seen so far which works great with Rails is [mini_fb](https://github.com/appoxy/mini_fb). You could start here.

Comment: good to hear that. please consider marking an answer as accepted if you think it solves your problem

Comment: Will do. One thing, not sure if you've had any experience publishing checkins to FB Places with this gem. Can't find anything in the gem docs - am using:

Comment: def places_checkin(checkin, text)
    MiniFB.enable_logging
    MiniFB.post(checkin.user.facebook_auth.token, 'me', 
      :type => 'checkins', 
      :message => text, 
      :place => checkin.producer.name, 
      :coordinates => {:latitude => checkin.lat, :longitude => checkin.lng}, 
      :application => FACEBOOK_APP_ID)
  end

Comment: but I get an OAuth error telling me long and lat are missing. I have also tried using an Array for lat and lng. Any idea what the correct format is?

Comment: not really. from what i've seen, the graph api is organized on id's. so everything should have an id, and should be able to be set by sending the id and some parameters, by a simple function. definetly read the graph api documentation about places before all. hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

fbgraph is facebook graph API gem for Rails 3.

you can find this from: https://github.com/nsanta/fbgraph

by using this, you can publish data to facebook wall as well as extract data from fb also.
I worked with this one of my required app.